# Make a condition in QGIS with other layers

Tags: qgis, layers

I want a QGIS composer form to change its color according to whether the value of an attribute of a layer matches a value, but for this I want to choose the attribute of a layer that is not the current.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `get_feature()` expression to get any feature of any layer in your project and then get an attribute value with the `attribute()` expression. The following example gets the population from the layer countries for Spain and puts it into a textfield in the mapcomposer. You can also use the obtained value to make some datadefined overrides like in your question:

```
attribute(get_feature('countries','name','Spain'),'pop_est')
```

[image]